# How to run modal operators after normal Blender operations

Tags: python, add-on

I'm trying to create a modal operator to detect the 3D cursor position when I click on the 3D_View area.

The final goal is to put instances of an object on the surface of another object until a RIGHTMOUSE event stops the operator functionality.

In the modal() method I read the "bpy.context.scene.cursor.location" property to get the 3d cursor position and return 'PASS_THROUGH' to make Blender complete its normal operation.

Since I tell Blender to complete its tasks, this means that my modal operator executes before Blender updates cursor position, so what I get is the position before the click.

I guess that executing the modal operator after the Blender normal operations would make me get the updated cursor position.

Is there any way to run an operator at the end of Blender's event handlers?

The operator code is below:

````
import bpy


class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal Operator"


    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE': 
            print(f"Left click: {bpy.context.scene.cursor.location}")
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}
            
        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:  # Cancel
            return {'FINISHED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalOperator)
    print("ModalOperator registered.")

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalOperator)
    print("ModalOperator unregistered.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

```
````

Comment: Isn't it normal for the mouse position to stay in the same location after a click? Do you want to monitor a drag event? Can you tell us the `event.type` you're monitoring?

Comment: Hello, please post the snippet of your code it would be easier to help you. Try `"FINISHED"`  instead of `"PASS_THROUGH"` I think it eats the event if you pass through.

Comment: I need to know what 3D position was assigned by Blender to the cursor when I left clicked.
I noticed that the position assigned to the cursor is on object surface if the mouse is over that object at click time and that's what I need.
I also need the operator to continue returning me click locations until I stop the operator functionality with a right mouse button click, so I can't use FINISHED to exit the modal() routine.